# Docker-machine mess up docker on host

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean, docker-machine

After creating a Ubuntu 16.04 Droplet in Digital Ocean I've tried to connect it with docker-machine from my local machine but the server's docker won't start. I actually attempted in two ways: first with docker installed on the server and the second without because it appears when you do the command `docker-machine create ...` it installs and overrides any docker on the server that ends up creating a failed instance of the docker there. I have the ports 22, 80, 443 and 2376 enabled in the firewall. Does machine create have an option to not install docker in the host?

```
$ docker-machine create --driver=generic \
                        --generic-ip-address=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX \
                        --generic-ssh-user=rinaldi \
                        --generic-ssh-key=C:/Users/[...]/id_rsa \
                        --generic-ssh-port=22 \
                        DigitalOcean
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(DigitalOcean) Importing SSH key...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Provisioning with ubuntu(systemd)...
Installing Docker...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
Error creating machine: Error running provisioning: ssh command error:
command : sudo systemctl -f start docker
err     : exit status 1
output  : Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

this is the systemctl -xe on the server

```
-- Unit docker.service has finished shutting down.
Sep 19 02:11:24 DigitalOcean systemd[1]: Closed Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit docker.socket has finished shutting down.
Sep 19 02:11:24 DigitalOcean systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has begun shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit docker.socket has begun shutting down.
Sep 19 02:11:24 DigitalOcean systemd[1]: Starting Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit docker.socket has begun starting up.
Sep 19 02:11:24 DigitalOcean systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit docker.socket has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Sep 19 02:11:24 DigitalOcean systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 19 02:11:24 DigitalOcean systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Sep 19 02:11:24 DigitalOcean systemd[1]: docker.socket: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 19 02:11:40 DigitalOcean sshd[3898]: Did not receive identification string from [...]
Sep 19 02:11:40 DigitalOcean sshd[6889]: Did not receive identification string from [...]
Sep 19 02:12:32 DigitalOcean kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=[...] SRC=[...] DST=[...] LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x0
Sep 19 02:12:40 DigitalOcean sudo[7183]:  rinaldi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/rinaldi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
Sep 19 02:12:40 DigitalOcean sudo[7183]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by rinaldi(uid=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears it's a bug on docker-machine 0.11 but it's fixed on 0.12 and if you need to get to work on 0.11 then here's the solution.

Replace this line in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/10-machine.conf` and then run systemctl daemon-reload should fix the problem.

```
 # ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H ...
 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H ...
```

Source:
https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/11#issuecomment-327441650